# LC Filter for a Full Wave Bridge Rectifier?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, rectifier, high-current, full-bridge

According to what I've read on a few websites and PDFs (http://www.irjes.com/Papers/vol2-issue6/Version-1/E02064249.pdf is an example) using an inductor-capacitor filter to assist AC to DC rectification in ripple management is much better than using either component by themselves. (In the example PDF capacitor was sized down by 75% & inductor was sized down by 94%)

How can I size the inductor and capacitor such that I can get a certain voltage ripple after being rectified by a full wave bridge rectifier? (Even in the paper they recommended a trial and error method, essentially guessing 25% for the capacitor and manually finding the inductance for the inductor)

I haven't taken differential equations yet, but I'm past Calculus III if you prefer to answer in a non algebraic way. (Although algebra is preferred)

I'm running 1kW (split phase, plans on moving to 3-phase) through this bridge (full wave) for high power electrochemistry: $$972W = 18V * 54A$$

Comment: so, you want a formula that will emit capacitor and inductor sizes for a given ripple level?  where are you planning to buy custom sized capacitors from?

Comment: When you get into the tens of amps, direct (mains frequency) rectification stops being a good idea, unless you really have to do things that way, I'd recommend an off-the-shelf smps, it'll have a much higher efficiency and will already have all the filtering builtin (the conduction losses in the rectifer alone will be 50+ watts, maybe even 100W, most diodes have between 0.5 - 1V drop and two are on at any one time in a full bridge rectifier)

Comment: @Jasen What are you talking about? You could just round the capacitance to the next highest number that people sell....

Comment: @Tom So either switch the frequency, or go with SMPS? As far as I can tell, SMPS still use bridge rectifiers though.

Comment: The higher power ones replace the diodes with mosfets for *really* low losses, also smps transformer waveforms are a lot more square so the rectified output looks almost flat *even before the filter capacitor*, well with some switching spikes thrown in. When rectifying 50/60hz AC, power only flows through the rectifier when the voltage in is higher than the voltage out, as this only happens during the peaks of the waveforms (as they're sinusoidal), all that energy is delivered in a sharp intense burst (the peak could easily be several times the average current).

Comment: @Tom Yeah, I've seen some of the ideal diode bridges schematics that use synchronous mosfets.

Comment: if you're going to the next size up, you might as well guess. there's only like 3 sizes per decade.

Comment: I should also mention that most kW+ smps units have some kind of Power Factor Correction (PFC) so that the current pulled from the mains is sinusoidal, if you wanted to use a big ol' mains transformer, there's no reason why you couldn't use pfc on the low voltage side to keep the transformer currents and voltages sinusoidal while providing a stable dc output after the pfc stage.

Answer (score 2):

did you read the last sentence of the paper?
"Since there is no mathematical formula available for designing a combined capacitor - inductor filter, the verified ATP model will help seniors,  graduate students, and design engineers to design a filter to limit the 
ripple to a specified value in an AC to DC converter."

If there is no mathematical solution available, you can only use try and error using a computer model or a real rectifier circuit.

Comment: I was uncertain if there actually was a mathematical formula and they didn't know about it/couldn't derive it/was found after publishing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

http://www.circuitstoday.com/filter-circuits

Ripple Factor = Vac rms/Vdc =   (√2/3)(Xc/XL) = (√2/3)(1/[2wc])(1/[2wL]) = 1/(6√2w2LC)